# Press enter in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm working on a dockerfile and I need to install a csgo server inside a container. For that I'm using LinuxGSM so i'm running :

```
RUN ./linuxgsm.sh csgoserver
```

This work fine but then csgoserver to be installed need to run this command :

```
RUN ./csgoserver install
```

But the problem is that the script csgoserver is waiting for host interactions and the field is filled with an "Y" already. I already tried using EOF, echo, DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive and printf without success...

Do you guys have an idea ? 
Thx.

My dockerfile in a complete version > https://codeshare.io/2jY3BM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to use

`RUN ./csgoserver auto-install`

instead of

`RUN ./csgoserver install`

as explained here: https://docs.linuxgsm.com/commands/install

> Run the install command: ./gameserver install or ./gameserver
>   auto-install to bypass any prompts. Follow on screen instructions.

Comment: @PaulMurith please don't forget to mark the  question as answered